# Google Chrome hosted app vs packaged app

Tags: google-chrome, hosted-app

I am confused about Chrome hosted app vs packaged app.

Hosted app
 - is where we hosted our web in server side
 - Required internet

Packaged app
 - hosted the website in client site
 - Just like a native app
 - No internet require.

I am interesting in Packaged app but can I make the packaged app just like drive.google.com or gmail?
When they are offline then using packaged app and when they are online and start syn the  pending offline files to server. Or packaged app is just everything in offline?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you out. 
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/choosing

Anyway you will have to host Packaged App if you want it cross platform i.e. web, mobile etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any functionality offline and online you want to go with the Packaged App. One way you can think about it is Packaged App download all the files required to run to the local machine. With Hosted Apps, all those files live on a web sever somewhere.

Packaged Apps are just like like regular web apps, but they have extra capabilities that allow them to run offline.

Also, Packaged Apps are not required to support offline.